# How to find triplet in list, then create new list holding triplets

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop

here is the question:

> Given two lists, find the first occurrence of triplets (three identical items) on both lists. If triplets are found in both lists, then return a new 6-element list containing both triplets. If no such triplets exist in a list, then a string "None" is added to the new list instead of a triplet. You must use one for loop and one while loop to implement this function.
>
> ```
> firstTripletPair([1, 2, 2, 2, 3], [3, 3, 3, 4]) → [2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]
> firstTripletPair([1, 2, 2, 2, 3], [1, 3, 3, 4]) → [2, 2, 2, 'None']
> firstTripletPair([1, 2, 2, 3, 3], [1, 3, 3, 4]) → ['None', 'None']
> ```

how would I solve this?
my code so far:

````
def firstTripletPair(list1,list2):
  newList = []
while (list1):
   newList.append(newList**6)
if len(list1) == len(set(list1)):
  return(newList**3)```
````

Comment: Solve the problem for a single list. You should perhaps make a separate function for this.

Comment: Iterate through a single list. Keep a record of the element from a previous iteration and compare that with the current one to see if it matches or not. If two previous iterations were matches, you got the triplet.